# Convert long value from java Date.getTime() to DateTime in VB.Net

Tags: java, vb.net

I have two difference application, one using java and other using VB.NET. The java application converted object to json and save to database as text as bellow

```
    [{"from_time":"07:30:00","end_time":"17:00:00","purpose":"","perform_date":1462035600000,"day_time":false,"night_time":false}]
```

perform_date:1462035600000 in java equal to "Sun May 01 00:00:00 ICT 2016", but I try to convert this number to DateTime in VB.NET but it show different date "01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM".

Test VB.NET Code

```
Dim d = New Date()
d.AddMilliseconds(1462035600000)
Console.WriteLine(CType(d, Date).ToString())
```

output:

```
01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM
```

Test Java Code:

```
long d = Long.parseLong("1462035600000");
performDate.setTime(d);
System.out.println(performDate.toString());
```

output:

```
Sun May 01 00:00:00 ICT 2016
```

What I did is wrong, I'm a newby on VB.NET. Please help

Comment: See my answer. The datetime you perform addmilliseconds to should be set prior to January 1st, 1970.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java use unix timestamp.
You need to initiate your Date at January 1st, 1970

If you are in the ICT timezone, you could probably use a datetime using LocaL as datetime kind. Otherwise, you can get the datetime as an UTC datetime, then manually add 7 hours to it.

```
Dim JavaTimeStamp As Long = 1462035600000
Dim MyDateTimeUTC as DateTime = GetUTCDateFromTimeStamp(JavaTimeStamp).addhours(7) 'Add 7 hours to match current ICT time (I had no consideration for saving time)
Dim MyDateTimeLocal as DateTime = GetLocalDateFromTimeStamp(JavaTimeStamp)
```

```
Public Function GetUTCDateFromTimeStamp(TimeStamp as long) As DateTime
    static startTime As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Utc)
    return Starttime.AddMilliseconds(TimeStamp)
End Function

Public function GetLocalDateFromTimeStamp(TimeStamp as long) as DateTime
      static startTime As New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Local)
    return Starttime.AddMilliseconds(TimeStamp)
End function
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it work for me. But my function d.AddMilliseconds(1462035600000)  not set d the new date value, It return the new date value. So I write this: d = d.AddMilliseconds(1462035600000)

Comment: Thanks - only meaningful answer I found to this special theme

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I don't use a good converter... haha but I found something interesting for you:

[Look at the example in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

As you can see, the function AddMilliseconds add milliseconds on a date which is declare before. You have to declare the date by default before add the milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer